# Fast Iteration in large ranges between 1 and 1*10^18 objects

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a range specified in type long which can be as great as from 1 and 1*10^18 inclusive, for each of the values between this range I do a divisibility check. I tested a for loop to see how long such an iteration would take (no operations just looping). Too long was the answer I found. I'm not familiar with another approach to gracefully do this. Can anyone share some ideas

Task:

possible example;
from N = 1 to N = 1*10^18, if N is divisible by X do something. Return number of N values that are divisible by X

Constraint, <=2 seconds for a result

Comment: You described your attempted failing solution, which is good. However, you are still missing a detailed description of the actual task you are trying to achieve (preferably with examples).

Comment: Actually, it is the `XY problem`. You must describe your current goal which you want to achieve.

Comment: Well there's no magical solution, you have a _lot_ of iterations to do and you can't escape the fact that you'll have to run them all (with n elements you can't go lower than n iterations). You can try multithreading to distribute the work, but whatever you do it will still be long. You may also try to find an algorithm which may "remove" paths so you have less and less values to test.

Comment: @TheJackal is there a chance that this problem is part of a top coder problem from a competition running right now?

Comment: @Ivaylo it is actually. Submitted, but I know it will fail for that range.

Comment: @TheJackal please do not post questions from ongoing contests. This is considered cheating

Comment: @Pierre-Luc could you expound on that further? Are you talking about directed graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop over the range and check divisibility because the only numbers in `[1,10^18]` divisible by `X` are `i * X` where `i` ranges from `1` to `10^18 / X` and there are exactly `10^18 / X` such numbers. If `X` is small this might still be a *lot* of numbers.

Comment: please delete your answer for the moment. As I stated this is most probably a competition problem from a competition that will be running for about 30 mins more. Your answer is absolutely correct but I don't think it is fair to solve problems like that.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. didn't realize how way off I was.

Comment: That's integer division by the way, or `floor(U / X)`, where U is the upper bound

Answer (score -1):

Yeah. Learn GPU programming. You need as many cores as you can get and then a lot of time.

the 1*10^18 side will take a lot of time. Seriously long time. No way to magically go around it.

A set of higher end graphics cards with proper programming can help - they are not super fast but they have thousands of cores each..... and are made for exactly this.